# freeCodeCamp Challenge - Basic Javascript - Profile Lookup Solution

Tags: javascript, properties, lookup

I want to know which one should I use between two approaches.
[**Profile Lookup**](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/profile-lookup) challenge.

I've got to a solution and it did work in this case. But, after this, I was looking for a different solution in **Get a Hint** session, and I've found a similar one, but using a method.

The only difference I see is the `hasOwnProperty()` method.

**My solution**

```js
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  // Only change code below this line
  for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i]["firstName"] === name) {
      if (contacts[i][prop]) {
      return contacts[i][prop]
      } else {
        return "No such property"
      }
    }
  }
  return "No such contact"
  // Only change code above this line
}
```

**Different solution**

```js
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  // Only change code below this line
  for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i]["firstName"] === name) {
      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      return contacts[i][prop]
      } else {
        return "No such property"
      }
    }
  }
  return "No such contact"
  // Only change code above this line
}
```

Mine, without that method, returns `undefined`, the other one with `hasOwnProperty()` returns `TRUE`.

Is there any difference besides that? Or it is just a matter of needing a boolean or a undefined return?

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` will only work if `prop` is defined _on_ the contact object, as opposed to being inherited from its `prototype` - however the exercise you linked-to does not use prototypes so the effective result is the same in both cases. (Also, you can do it in 2 lines: `const c = contacts.find( i => i.firstName === name ); return c && ( prop in c ) ? c[prop] : ( c ? "No such property" : "No such contact" );` )

Comment: If `contacts[i][prop]` is a **falsy** value, your approach will fail.